# Spaces in filename in Zend Framework action similar to readfile

Tags: zend-framework, readfile

I grabbed this bit of code from the PHP.net readfile page:

```
<?php

// Action controller
public function someAction() {

    $response = $this->_response;

    // Disable view and layout rendering
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();

    // Process the file
    $file = 'whatever.zip';
    $bits = @file_get_contents($file);
    if(strlen($bits) == 0) {
        $response->setBody('Sorry, we could not find requested download file.');
    }
    else {
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream', true);
        $response->setBody($bits);
    }
}

?>
```

It works great with most files but when I test it on a file with spaces in the filename, it says it can't find the requested file. Any suggestions, or is there a better way to do a readfile in Zend Framework where the filename can have spaces in it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) manual page:

> **Note:** If you're opening a URI with
>   special characters, such as spaces,
>   you need to encode the URI with
>   [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

*(Edit: Use `rawurlencode()` to convert spaces to `%20` instead of `+`)*

So, you need to [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) the filename before using it:

```
$file = rawurlencode('whatever.zip');
```

Comment: No dice there. It puts +'s in the name and I get the message saying "Sorry, we could not find requested download file."

Comment: You're right. Use `rawurlencode()` instead. This translates spaces to `%20` instead of `+`. Don't use `str_replace()` :)

Comment: I couldn't get rawurlencode() to work either. 
Just curious, why don't use str_replace()?

Comment: Using `str_replace()` makes for fragile and unmaintainable code - you're essentially writing a hack to manually encode the space character. `rawurlencode()` will encode *all* non-alnum characters so your code doesn't break when you suddenly get a filename with a `@` or `^` character.

Comment: `rawurlencode()` may not be working if you run it on a directory path, since it will also encode slashes. It is designed to run on only the filename part of a URI. If you're downloading a file from a directory, just append the encoded filename to the directory path. See the PHP Manual for usage examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the space in the filename with a string replace and now it works:

```
$file = str_replace(" ","%20",$file);
```